# Overwrite specific XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0, overwrite

Let's say I have a file like this:

```
<outer>
  <inner>
    <nodex attr="value1">text</attr>
    <nodex attr="value2">text</attr>
  </inner>
</outer>
```

Basically what I want to do is, in C# (constrained to .net 2.0 here), this (pseudocode):

```
foreach node
    if(node eq 'nodex')
        update attr to newvalue
```

When complete, the xml file (on disk) should look like:

```
<outer>
  <inner>
    <nodex attr="newvalue1">text</attr>
    <nodex attr="newvalue2">text</attr>
  </inner>
</outer>
```

These two look marginally promising:

[Overwrite a xml file value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948027/overwrite-a-xml-file-value)

[Setting attributes in an XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589048/setting-attributes-in-an-xml-document)

But it's unclear whether or not they actually answer my question.

---

I've written this code in the meantime:

Here's a more minimal case which works:

```
    public static void UpdateXML()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("XMLFile1.xml"))
        {
            doc.Load(reader);
            XmlNodeList list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("nodex");
            foreach (XmlNode node in list)
            {
                node.Attributes["attr"].Value = "newvalue";
            }
        }
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("XMLFile1.xml"))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample script that can be run from [LinqPad](http://linqpad.net)

```
var x = @"<outer>
  <inner>
    <nodex attr=""value1"">text</nodex>
    <nodex attr=""value2"">text</nodex>
  </inner>
</outer>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(x);

foreach (XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("//nodex"))
{
    n.Attributes["attr"].Value = "new" + n.Attributes["attr"].Value.ToString();
}

doc.OuterXml.Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest solution would be to use a loop with [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)/[XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). That way you do not need to load the whole xml in memory.

In pseudocode:

```
while (reader.read)
{
   if (reader.Node.Name == "nodex")
       ......

   writer.write ...
}
```

You can [check here for ideas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As starting point you can show us what you have tried, you could use XPATH to select the nodes you want to modify, search for select node by attribute value in xpath.

After you have found the nodes you want to update you can reassign the attribute value as needed with a normal assignment.